# Linear transformation, norm and matrix

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Let $T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R^{n}},\mathbb{R^{m}})$ and $A=[a_{ij}] \in \mathcal{M}_{m\times n}$ the matrix associated to $T$. Let:

$$\mu := \max_{i=\overline{1,m} \\ j=\overline{1,n}}|a_{ij}| $$

Prove the following relationship:

$$\mu \leq \| T \| \leq \mu \sqrt{mn}$$

Comment: What is $||T||$? Could you explain?

Comment: @RedPhoenix is the norm of T (I think is the maximm norm, but I'm not sure).

Comment: I got it. I have answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that $||T||$ is supremum of the set $\{|Tx| \hspace{0.3cm} | \hspace{0.3cm} \text{where} \hspace{0.3cm} |x|=1\}$ (say $K$). There is $a_{ij}$ such that $|a_{ij}|=\mu$. So if we choose $v=(0,0,...0,1,0,...,0)$ where only $j^{th}$ term is $1$ others are zero, then $|Tv|$ is in $K$. So $||T||\geq |Tv| \geq |a_{ij}| = \mu$.

Let $B \in \mathcal{M}_{m\times n}$ such that all entries are $\mu$. So $||T||\leq ||B||$. $||B||=\mu||C||$ where $C$ is the matrix whose all entries are only $1$ in $\mathcal{M}_{m\times n}$. $||C||=|C . (1/\sqrt{n},1/\sqrt{n},...,1/\sqrt{n})|=|(\sqrt{n},\sqrt{n},...,\sqrt{n})|=\sqrt{mn}$. Thus $||T||\leq ||B|| =\mu ||C|| \leq \mu \sqrt{mn}$

Hence we have $\mu \leq ||T|| \leq \mu \sqrt{mn}$