# Inequality with a matrix norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $T\in \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)$ and $A = [a_{ij}] \in \mathcal M_{m\times n}$ the associated matrix of this transformation. If $\mu := \max \{ |a_{ij}| : i =1, \dots, m; j = 1, \dots, n\}$, prove that $\mu \leq \| T\| \leq \mu \sqrt{mn}$.

For the lower bound I think I might write that $\| Tx\|_{\infty} \leq \| T\|_{\infty}$ for every $x$ s.t. $\| x\|_{\infty} = 1$. Then, noting that we can take $x$ as any vector from the canonical base of $\mathbb R^n$ see that $\mu \leq \| T\|_{\infty}$, and by the fact the the norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent conclude that $\mu \leq \| T\|$. However, I'm I'm not sure of this reasoning and how to get the upper bound.

Comment: You have two norms in your question, $\|T\|_\infty$ and $\|T\|$. I suppose the former is the induced maximum norm (i.e. the absolute row sum norm). What is the latter one?

Comment: @user1551: $\| T\| = \sup\{ \|T x\| : \| x\| = 1\}$

Comment: Then the problem statement is false and unrelated to $\|T\|_\infty$. Do you want to prove $\mu\le\|T\|_\infty\le\mu\sqrt{mn}$ instead?

Comment: @user1551: Most likely my proof for the lower bound is wrong. I want to prove that $\mu \leq \| T\| \leq \mu \sqrt{mn}$

Comment: Is $\|x\|$ some specific vector norm or a generic vector norm?

Comment: @user1551: Generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. Let $m=n\ge2,\ c>0$ and
$$
P=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&1/c\\ &&I_{n-2}},\ T=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0\\ &&\mathbf0}.
$$
Define $\|x\|=\|Px\|_2$. Then
\begin{aligned}
\|T\|
&=\max_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|\\
&=\max_{\|Px\|_2=1}\|PTx\|_2\\
&=\max_{\|Px\|_2=1}\|(PTP^{-1})Px\|_2\\
&=\max_{\|v\|_2=1}\|(PTP^{-1})v\|_2\\
&=\|PTP^{-1}\|_2\\
&=\left\|\pmatrix{0&c\\ 0&0\\ &&\mathbf0}\right\|_2=c.
\end{aligned}
Hence $\|T\|=c<\max_{i,j}|t_{ij}|=1$ when $c$ is sufficiently small and $\|T\|=c>\max_{i,j}|t_{ij}|\sqrt{mn}$ when $c$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: How did you go from the generic norm $\| \cdot \|$ to  $\| \cdot \|_2$?

Comment: @Keio203 The norm here isn't generic. The inequality is true for some norms but not for the others. To show that it doesn't hold for all matrix norms, it suffices to exhibit a counterexample that uses a specific matrix norm $\|T\|$.

Comment: I just realized this question was already asked here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3938932/linear-transformation-norm-and-matrix where a proof is provided. So I'm confused whether the statement is true or not.

Comment: @Keio203 As I said, the inequality is true for *some* norms. The linked answer in particular proves the inequality when $\|T\|=\|T\|_\infty$. However, as you asked whether the inequality is true for a generic norm, i.e. whether it is true for *all* norms, the answer is negative, as shown by the counterexample in my answer.